# Find X as a Function of Ampltiude

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

For a spring-mass system undergoing simple harmonic motion find the location(s) between -A and A where the spring potential energy is equal to the kinetic energy. You should find x as a function of amplitude, A, only.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you use the equation of the classical harmonic oscillator, and you will find, by solving the equation, the function $x(t)$. Calculate the potential and the kinetic energy as functions of x.